# Anybody know what this avconv line does?

Tags: avconv

avconv -y -i input.avi -b 915k -an -f mp4 -ar 44100 -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -strict experimental -shortest -vcodec libx264 output.mp4 -loglevel fatal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this seems to be an old version of avconv, since the command line has changed since then (but not too much).

So, let's break it down:

-y

This answers 'yes' to questions like "do you want to overwrite the output file".

```
-i input.avi
```

This gives the program the file input.avi as an input

```
-b 915k
```

This asks to change the bitrate to 915 Kibibytes per second

```
-an
```

This removes all the audio from the output.

```
-f mp4
```

Sets up MP4 as the format of the output file

```
-ar 44100
```

This sets audio sampling rate of the following input file.

```
-f s16le
```

This sets the format of the audio of the following input file.

```
-ac 2
```

This sets number of channels of audio to two.

```
 -i /dev/zero
```

This adds another input file that consists entirely of zero input

```
 -acodec libfaac
```

This reencodes the audio (silence most likely) with libfaac

```
 -ab 128k
```

Setting the audio bitrate to 128 Kbps

```
 -strict experimental
```

Allows avconv to use nonstandard approaches while encoding.

```
-shortest
```

Ends encoding when the shortest of the inputs has ended. This is needed because /dev/zero will never end.

```
-vcodec libx264
```

This sets the library to do the video encoding. The codec will be (unfortunately) h264

```
 output.mp4
```

This is the name of the output file

```
 -loglevel fatal
```

Fatal messages will be written as the log, and that's it.

In the future you may find `man avconv` to be your friend.

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why someone would disable audio with the flag,  then set a bunch of audio settings?

(I'm trying to reverse engineer a program that may or may not make sense.)

Comment: Because a person wanted an audio track that was silent... for whatever reason. Basically the sound from the input file is substituted with /dev/zero. What was this needed? Who knows.